# Perplexed by css discrepancy during runtime

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

I have the following in the .css file when the application is not running:

```
   #tabsuseradmin .ui-tabs-panel {
        height: 500px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

But during runtime, in the browser developer, the same styling comes as:

```
 #tabsuseradmin .ui-tabs-panel {
        height: 900px;
        overflow: auto;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
```

I searched "900px" in my entire Visual Studio project, and did not see it anywhere for a `height` attribute. I am stuck on this and don't know what is happening to cause this to become 900px. What should I do?

Load order of my CSS files:

```
<link href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="/content/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/content/docsupport/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/content/uielements.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/content/headerfooter.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The `uielements.css` contains the styling in question, and the `headerfooter.css` doesn't contain anything that overwrites in the css above it (I tested by removing it entirely).

Thank you.

Comment: are you using any type of css framework? what browser are you using?

Comment: @JayLane I am using IE11. The same thing happens in Firefox. I am not using any css framework. Also, I have cleared the cache to make sure old CSS files aren't being loaded.

Comment: What do you mean by runtime and when the application is not running?

Comment: check for any overridden styles for either of the classes

Comment: Check your cache.

Comment: @LucasLazaro already cleared cache

Comment: @Geeky if it was overridden, shouldn't I find a height attribute of 900px somewhere?

Comment: @ITWorker not necessarily if its being overwritten by calculation in a js file.

Comment: @j08691The css file contained within the ASP.NET MVC project structure contains the height attribute of 500px (which is what I want) and when I launch the application the browser's version of the file contains 900px for the height attribute.

Comment: @JayLane in that case, is there any setting where I can specify to ignore any calculations or overrides?

Comment: @ITWorker what 3rd party js/css libraries are currently in your project. It looks like from your class names that you have atleast JQuery and JQueryUI in the project. Anything else?

Comment: @ITWorker: no, you can't. You have two options: A. Find the script that modifies your element and disable/alter it. or B. Specify a stronger CSS selector in your stylesheet than the one currently applying.

Comment: @JayLane yes I do have those two, as well as bootstrap

Comment: This would be ***a lot easier*** if you provided a [mcve] of your issue or at least a live example, if you can't reproduce it out of its context. Besides, you said you're not using any CSS framework than said you're using Bootstrap, which is a CSS framework.

Comment: @ITWorker yeah there is no way to disable it other than going through the file and removing the function. Did you try applying max-height?

Comment: @ITWorker can you list the load order of your css files

Comment: @ITWorker try adding a style tag after the loading of the css files with your 500px rule to see if it then takes precedence if not the issue will be in one of the js files.

Comment: @JayLane please see edit, I have added the order.

Comment: @JayLane great that worked! I put a style tag just for this element and it did the trick. I will accept it as the answer if you post it. Thanks!

Comment: @ITWorker done!

Comment: I do agree with @andi that I didn't really help solve this issue but put a bandaid on the issue. If you can provide me with a link to your site so I can take a better look with dev tools I can help diagnose exactly what is causing the discrepancy with the css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Load your css files inside of your head tag, after the loading of the files create a style tag with the rules that you want to take precedence immediately after the css file loading. This will allow your rule to overwrite preexisting rules set in the css library files.

Comment: OP needs to figure out where his conflict is, not just override it with some extra CSS.  I know you added this as an answer just because the OP said he'd give you some points, but it doesn't belong as an answer.

Comment: @andi to me this is an answer, based on my own criteria for level of effort needed vs. end result. I would have considered researching more if the issue was widespread, but to me this is fine for one scenario that is very minor.